# Elasticsearch not working with 'not_analyzed' index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

I am unable to figure out why elasticsearch not searching with not_analysed indexes. I have following settings in my model,

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
      mappings dynamic: 'false' do
        indexes :id
        indexes :name, index: 'not_analyzed'
        indexes :email, index: 'not_analyzed'
        indexes :contact_number
      end
    end

    def as_indexed_json(options = {})
      as_json(only: [ :id, :name, :username, :user_type, :is_verified, :email, :contact_number ])
    end
```

And my mapping at elasticsearch is right, as below.

```
{
  "users-development" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "user" : {
        "dynamic" : "false",
        "properties" : {
          "contact_number" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "email" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But issue is when I make search on not analyzed fields (name and email, as I wanted them to be not analyzed) it only search on full word. Like in the example below it should have return John, Johny and Tiger, all 3 records. But it only returns 2 of the records.

I am searching as below

```
  settings = {
    query: {
      filtered: {
        filter: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              { terms: { name: [ "john", "tiger" ] } },
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    size: 10
  }

  User.__elasticsearch__.search(settings).records
```

This is how I am creating index on my user object in callback `after_save`,

```
User.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create(
                index: User.index_name,
                id: self.id,
                body: self.as_indexed_json,
              )
```

Some of the document that should match

```
[{
      "_index" : "users-development",
      "_type" : "user",
      "_id" : "670",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"id":670,"email":"john@monkeyofdoom.com","name":"john baba","contact_number":null}
    },
    {
          "_index" : "users-development",
          "_type" : "user",
          "_id" : "671",
          "_score" : 1.0,
          "_source":{"id":671,"email":"human@monkeyofdoom.com","name":"Johny Rocket","contact_number":null}
        }

    , {
          "_index" : "users-development",
          "_type" : "user",
          "_id" : "736",
          "_score" : 1.0,
          "_source":{"id":736,"email":"tiger@monkeyofdoom.com","name":"tiger sherof", "contact_number":null}
        } ]
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: what is user_type in above query?

Comment: how did you index? "John" or 'john'? could you show us the document that you think should match?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 added the documents that should match

Comment: @ChintanShah25 thanks for the suggestion actually it is only search for partial word like if the names would be John Baba and Johny Rocket, and the query string is John -- It  should have returned 2 records but it is only returning a single record i.e John. Any suggestions Thanks

Comment: looking at your documents, you wont get any results. What is your requirements? what should match and what should not? also how johny would match john?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 sorry for the confusion, at one place I needed to search via wildcard for that I am doing "john*" and at one place I needed to search from array where I have to search on exact match thats the reason I have to add not_analyzed index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would get desired results with [keyword toknizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) combined with [lowercase filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) rather than using `not_analyzed`.

The reason `john*` did not match *Johny* was due to case sensitivity.
This setup will work

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now john* will match johny. You should be using `multi-fields` if you have various requirements. `terms query` for *john* wont give you *john baba* as inside inverted index there is no token as *john*. You could use standard analyzer on one field and keyword analyzer on other.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation `term query`

> The term query finds documents that contain the exact term specified in the inverted index.

You are searching for `john` but none of your documnents contain `john` i.e why you were not getting any result. Either you can your field `analysed` and then apply `query string` or search for exact term.

Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-term-query.html for more details